# How to make Octave interpret function arguments as numbers?

Tags: function, octave

I have this function in a separate file (my_test_func1.m)

```
function y = my_test_func1 (x)
y = x + 0;
endfunction
```

the result of it in the command console 49 for 1, 50 for 2 and so on. So I assume Octave takes my input as strings, not as numbers. How to tell it that I want to use numbers?

I run Octave on Windows - "i686-pc-mingw32"

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured it out. I should call the function as

```
my_test_func1(2)
```

not

```
my_test_func1 2
```

In the first case it's a number, in the second - string. Super obvious (and safe).